# How to implement resize() to change capacity of dynamic member data in c++

Tags: c++, class, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-class

I need to implement the function **resize() :**

```
 void IntSet::resize(int new_capacity)
 {
     if (new_capacity < used)
         new_capacity = used;
     if (used == 0)
         new_capacity = 1;

     capacity = new_capacity;

     int * newData = new int[capacity];

     for (int i = 0; i < used; ++i)
         newData[i] = data[i];

     delete [] data;
     data = newData;
}
```

inside the functions :

```
 IntSet IntSet::unionWith(const IntSet& otherIntSet) const
 {
       IntSet unionSet = otherIntSet;

       for (int i = 0; i < used; i++)
       {
           if (unionSet.contains(data[i]))
              unionSet.add(data[i]);
       }
       return unionSet;
 }
```

and this one:  *( NOTE: that I have it already inside the add() function but I think it is incorrect)*

```
 bool IntSet::add(int anInt)
 {
     if (contains(anInt) == false)
     {
        if (used >= capacity)
           resize(used++);

        data[used++] = anInt;

        return true;
     }
     return false;
 }
```

The program compiles correctly without errors, but it does give me an error of  ***Segmentation fault***

**NOTE: The main thing is that I need help in learning how to use the resize function to resize the *capacity* of the the dynamic member data. Also, I know vectors would help in this case, but we are not allowed to use vectors yet**

Here is the **Special Requirements** from professor:

```
>Special Requirement (You will lose points if you don't observe this.) <br/>

>When calling resize *(while implementing some of the member functions)* to 
>increase the capacity of the dynamic arrays, use the following resizing 
>rule (unless the new capacity has to be something else higher as dictated 
>by other >overriding factors): <br/>
>
>*"new capacity" is "roughly 1.5 x old capacity" and at least "old capacity 
> + 1".* <br/>
>
>The latter *(at least " old capacity + 1 ")* is a simple way to take care 
>of the subtle case where " 1.5 x old capacity " evaluates (with truncation) 
>to the >same as "old capacity". <br/>
```

Comment: Unrelated notes: `if (used >= capacity) resize(used++);` if `used` is greater than `capacity` you've already lost. Something has already gotten smashed. ""new capacity" is "roughly 1.5 x old capacity" and at least "old capacity 
> + 1"." 1.5 is better than one by a wide margin. Otherwise you are constantly resizing.

Comment: then how can I check if I need to resize? or should I just automatically resize unless I only do if (used == capacity)  and resize ((1.5 * capacity) + 1) ?? I am a little confused with this

Comment: `used == capacity` the other bit requires more than I can put and explain in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

When you `resize` because of `add`, you increment `used` twice.

```
bool IntSet::add(int anInt)
{
    if (contains(anInt) == false)
    {
       if (used >= capacity)
          resize(used++);  // Here And this is a post increment. 
                           // resize will be called with used before the increment
                           // so you will wind up asking for a buffer the same size.

       data[used++] = anInt; // and here. 

       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

So nothing goes into used. You skip a space and write into the space after. Plus `resize(used++);` didn't ask for more space, so you actually wind up writing two spots outside the allocated storage, and this probably triggers the segfault.

Solution

You don't want to increment anything at `resize(used++);`. You want to add one to the `capacity`, but not increment it, so

```
resize(capacity +1);
```

Looks about right. However, what the instructions asked for is something more like:

```
int newcap = capacity * 1.5;
if (newcap == capacity) // newcap didn't change. eg: 1*1.5 = 1
{
    newcap ++;
}
resize(newcap);
```

This is brute force though. There are smarter ways to do this.

Comment: Thank you! I actually ended up using this and it worked.
          `resize(int(1.25 * capacity) + 1);`